# OperationalError: unrecognized token sqlite3, python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I keep getting an error that states OperationalError: unrecognized token:. I am trying to insert data into a database using sql however when the program starts I have no knowledge of the number of fields I will need as this changes on a case by case basis. Therefore, I have been attempting to use a for loop to create a string to be inserted into a sql statement which will allow me to insert the data into a database.

```
    for y in Data_rearrange:
        g = y.replace(" ", "_")
        g = "'[" + g + "]'"
        DataString = DataString + g
        print(g)
        if y != Data_rearrange[-1]:
            DataString = DataString + ", "
    print(DataString)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Jackson VALUES (" + DataString + ")")
```

Does anyone know what part of the sql statement is throwing up the error?
Many thanks

EDIT

'[Pro_Series_Dinky_DK2,_Ebony_Fingerboard,_Satin_Orange_Blaze]', '[2914105580]', '[Pro_Series]', '[$1156.45]', '[Satin_Orange_Blaze]', '[Dinky]', '[Alder]', '[Gloss_Poly]', '[1-Piece_Bolt-On_Maple_Speed_Neck_with_Graphite_Reinforcement_and_Scarf_Joint]', '[25.5"_(648_mm)]', '[12"_to_16"_Compound_Radius_(304.8_mm_to_406.4_mm)]', '[24]', '[Jumbo]', '[Floyd_Rose_R3_Locking]', '[1.6875"_(42.86_mm)]', '[Jackson_Pointed_6-In-Line]', '[4-Bolt]', '[Satin]', '[Ebony]', '[Abalone_Dot]', '[Direct_Mount_Seymour_Duncan_Zebra_JB_TB4_Humbucking]', '[Direct_Mount_Seymour_Duncan_'59_Zebra_Humbucking]', '[Master_Volume,_Master_Tone]', '[5-Position_Blade:_Position_Position._1._Full_Bridge_Pickup,_Position_2._Bridge_Inner_Coil,_Position_3._Both_Inner_Coils,_Position_4._-_Neck_Inner_Coil,_Position_5._-_Full_Neck_Pickup]', '[HH]', '[Floyd_Rose_FRT-O2000_Double-Locking_Tremolo_(Recessed)]', '[Jackson_Sealed_Die-Cast]', '[Right-Hand]', '[None]', '[Black_Dome_Style]', '[NPS,_.009-.042_Gauges]'

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: maybe a problem with simple quotes? Can you show us the value of `(" + DataString + ")"`

Comment: Or show an example for the value of `Data_rearrange` which generates the error, along with the initial value of `DataString` before the loop gets called.

Comment: I've added the DataString as you asked, the initial value of the DataString before the loop is called is just an empty string

Comment: No worries problem solved, thanks all for your help. The dialogue really helped